# redux saga knowing when task is done

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have the following saga:

```
function* someSaga(action) {
  const { currentUser: { accountId } } = action;

  const accountBillingPlanEffect = yield call(getAccountBillingPlan, services['account-billing-plans'], accountId);
  const accountBillingPlanResponse = yield (accountBillingPlanEffect.payload.promise);
  const { stripeSubscriptionId } = accountBillingPlanResponse.data[0];

  const stripeSubscriptionEffect = yield call(getStripeSubscription, services['stripe/subscriptions'], stripeSubscriptionId);
  const stripeSubscriptionResponse = yield (stripeSubscriptionEffect.payload.promise);
  const { customer } = stripeSubscriptionResponse.data[0];

//The important part
  const [stripeCustomerTask, stripeInvoicesTask] = yield all([
    fork(getStripeCustomer, services['stripe/customers'], customer),
    fork(getStripeInvoices, services['stripe/invoices'], customer),
  ]);

}
```

How can I know when **[stripeCustomerTask, stripeInvoicesTask]** are done?

I would like to execute another action when each one of them is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's in the `all([...])`, and you're yielding on it, you can just put your code immediately after. The code after it won't execute until those values are returned. You're good to go! just keep coding.

[This is one of the best `redux-sagas` blogs I have read to date](https://formidable.com/blog/2017/composition-patterns-in-redux-saga/) which covers this pretty nicely. The key part here being:

> redux-saga provides the `all` effect, which takes an array of blocking effects and waits for all of them to complete before resuming with all results.

So, you can just put your code right after the `all`, and expect to have the values.

```
//The important part
const [stripeCustomerTask, stripeInvoicesTask] = yield all([
  fork(getStripeCustomer, services['stripe/customers'], customer),
  fork(getStripeInvoices, services['stripe/invoices'], customer),
]);
// keep coding
if (stripeCustomerTask) { ... }
```

Comment: Ohh thanks for the blog, it was amazing to read, now everything make sense!!! :)))